# i want to print the client name in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

my original path is  D:\FTP\testftp\clientname\Folder\EDW
where under EDW there are files
i am trying to fetch the latest file and oldest file with file count but in output i want client name also but i am getting name of folder

can any one help how to get the client name in output
here is my script

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FTP\testftp\*\EDW' -Recurse -Directory | 
Select Name,FullName,
@{Name='Latestfile';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -last 1).Name}},
@{Name='LastestFileTime';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *-SALES.csv| Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -last 1).lastWriteTime}},
@{Name='OldestFile';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName  *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -first 1).Name}},
@{Name='OldestFileTime';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName  *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -first 1).lastWriteTime}},
@{Name='count';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse| Measure-Object).Count}}
```

and its output

```
Name            : EDW
FullName        : D:\FTP\testftp\clientname\folder\EDW
Latestfile      : HIST-SALES.CSV
LastestFileTime : 11/20/2015 11:08:59 AM
OldestFile      : -SALES.CSV
OldestFileTime  : 11/21/2025 4:08:49 AM
count           : 173
```

Comment: instead of `.Name`, use `.Parent.Parent` to get the `.Name` of the dir that is two levels up.

Comment: where exactly you are telling to change ?
actually i am newbie to powershell

 @Lee_Dailey

Comment: use a calculated property. [*grin*] for instance, if this directory `d:\ftp\testFtp\ClientName\folder\edw` is loaded into `$Test`, then this `$Test.Parent.Parent.Name` will give you `ClientName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another calculated property to include the client name. We can derive that folder from the `FullName` by splitting the path into parts by the `\`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FTP\testftp\*\EDW' -Recurse -Directory | 
Select Name,FullName,
@{Name='Latestfile';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -last 1).Name}},
@{Name='LastestFileTime';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *-SALES.csv| Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -last 1).lastWriteTime}},
@{Name='OldestFile';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName  *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -first 1).Name}},
@{Name='OldestFileTime';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName  *-SALES.csv | Where {$_.lastWriteTime} | select -first 1).lastWriteTime}},
@{Name='count';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse| Measure-Object).Count}},
@{Name='Client';Expression={($_.FullName -split '\\')[3]}}
```

Comment: Name            : EDW
FullName        : D:\FTP\testftp\tomsford\Processed\EDW
Latestfile      : HIST-140163-20151120-SALES.CSV
LastestFileTime : 11/20/2015 11:08:59 AM
OldestFile      : 140163-20151121-SALES.CSV
OldestFileTime  : 11/21/2015 4:08:49 AM
count           : 1722

Key   : Expression
Value : ($_.FullName -split '\\')[3]
Name  : Expression

Key   : Name
Value : Client
Name  : Name


getting this output not getting expected output
@AdminofThings

Comment: Try it again. There needed to be another comma